# 時代 and 時 difference

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between, say, 子供の時 and 子どもの時代?

Comment: See also: 子供の頃…

Answer (score 4):

～の時 (read とき{HL}) is half a suffix rather than a noun, nearly equals "when ~". So 子供の時 literally translates into "when (I was) a child".

子供の時代 means "the age of children". I don't know what it is, but it sounds very poetic. Probably what you really wanted is **子供時代**; it means "childhood", and if used adverbly, "in one's childhood".
(**EDIT**: Thus, if you compare 子供の時 and 子供時代, they show little difference in meaning but 子供時代 sounds more noun-like and literary.)

They are so confusing, but when you say ～の時代, it only stands for some historical period, but ～時代 can also refer a certain stage in someone's life history (e.g. 学生時代, 記者時代, 女優時代 etc.).

Comment: What about 高校時代 and 高校の時?  Thats what prompted me to ask the question

Comment: @Daniel Semantically I don't think they really make any difference. Just saying the same thing in different ways. But 高校時代 sounds slightly more literary, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is slight, but there definitely is a difference.  The easiest way to think of it in my opinion is that "の時" means "when" and "の時代" means "generation".

So, for your example, I would translate them as follows:

子供の時 - When I was a kid

子供の時代 - Our generation when I was young

So, you can see that the "時代" translation doesn't work too well, and this is largely because "時代" is very context heavy.  So, a good example would be a conversation like this:

"あなたは25歳の時に携帯電話あったでしょう？"

"うん、ありましたよ。"

"私たちの時代はなかったよ。"

So, this would roughly translate as follows:

"When you were 25 years old, there were cell phones, weren't there?"

"Yes, there were."

"My generation didn't have them."

You can see here that "の時" didn't need much context around it, and since the context has already been established, "の時代" becomes much easier to translate.  Furthermore, "の時" carries a bit more specificity to it.  By using "25歳の時" it definitely sounds like we're talking about a very specific year, but using "私たちの時代" sounds more like we're talking about the speakers years between about 20 and 30.

The two are very, very similar, and my explanation may not be the best, but I hope this gives you a bit more insight into the differences between the two!

Comment: Thing is, I've seen it as 高校時代, and I don't know why 高校の時 isn't used instead.

Answer (score 1):

「子供の時」: The time when you were a child. (Similar expression:  「子供の頃（ころ）」）

「時代」is basically equivalent to "era" such like 「江戸時代 in the Edo era」(a certain term in history.)
In Japan, a name of an era changes when the emperor changes.

子供の時に、父と富士山（ふじさん: Mt. Fuji)に登りました。
（= 子供の頃に、父と富士山に登りました。）